# MediaView do not show a mp4

Tags: javafx

My media player is not working. But there is no error in execution.

I'm using an FXML file to generate the `MediaView`.
`Media` and `MediaPlayer` is generated via `initialize`.

Normally, the video would have to play directly, but it don´t.

```
public class Controller  {


    @FXML
    private MediaView mediaView;

    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private Media me;


    @FXML
    void play(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("test");
        String path = new File("src/video/video.mp4").getAbsolutePath();
        me = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
        //me = new Media(getClass().getResource("../video/video.mp4").toExternalForm());
        mp = new MediaPlayer(me);
        mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mp);
        mp.setAutoPlay(true);



    }



}
```

Path is correct. Controller works

Comment: Did you check the [`Media.error`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#errorProperty) property?

Comment: I dont get any Exception.